# Creating Store in GeoServer using ImageMosaic Plugin gives Error?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic

I am creating a GeoServer 2.4.1 store with GeoTiffs using the Image Mosaic Plugin and I get the following error when pressing the  button

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: 
Failed to create reader from file://C:\Geoserver Rasters\GeoTiffs\ and hints null
```

The Shape File describing the GeoTiffs IS Created in the directory.

I have tied with a single GeoTiff as well as multile files, same error.

I CAN create a store with the single tif file using the GEOTIFF Raster Data Store successfully but when using the ImageMosaic Plugin, it fails

Is there a problem with the file? How to I get these GeoTiff Files to display?

GDALINFO Reports the following on the single test file:

```
        Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
        Files: originals\200k--e51-32_clip.tif
           originals\200k--e51-32_clip.aux
           originals\200k--e51-32_Clip.rrd
           originals\200k--e51-32_clip.tif.aux.xml
        Size is 4203, 2906
        Coordinate System is:
        GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
        Origin = (120.999860000000000,16.666795000000000)
        Pixel Size = (0.000237994587000,-0.000229480662000)
        Metadata:
         AREA_OR_POINT=Area
         TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
         TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IMAGINE TIFF Support
        Copyright 1991 - 1999 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved
        @(#)$RCSfile: etif.c $ $Revision: 1.10.1.9.1.9.2.11 $ $Date: 2004/09/15 18:42:01
        EDT $
         TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
         TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
         Image Structure Metadata:
         INTERLEAVE=BAND
         Corner Coordinates:
        Upper Left  ( 120.9998600,  16.6667950) (120d59'59.50"E, 16d40' 0.46"N)
        Lower Left  ( 120.9998600,  15.9999242) (120d59'59.50"E, 15d59'59.73"N)
        Upper Right ( 122.0001512,  16.6667950) (122d 0' 0.54"E, 16d40' 0.46"N)
        Lower Right ( 122.0001512,  15.9999242) (122d 0' 0.54"E, 15d59'59.73"N)
        Center      ( 121.5000056,  16.3333596) (121d30' 0.02"E, 16d20' 0.09"N)
        Band 1 Block=64x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
          Overviews: 1051x727, 526x364, 263x182, 132x91, 66x46
          Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
        0: 212,215,170,255
        1: 208,210,150,255
        2: 215,181,155,255
        3: 185,207,146,255
        4: 150,150,153,255
        5: 38,102,155,255
        6: 113,108,44,255
        7: 243,220,212,255
        8: 112,78,41,255
        9: 143,78,43,255
        10: 138,103,44,255
        11: 175,112,77,255
        12: 240,215,181,255
        13: 112,108,74,255
        14: 171,136,80,255
        15: 28,87,93,255
        16: 111,112,111,255
        17: 182,211,178,255
        18: 187,255,185,255
        19: 112,216,248,255
        20: 76,77,75,255
        21: 110,43,7,255
        22: 109,75,13,255
        23: 185,251,207,255
        24: 177,255,254,255
        25: 2,1,0,255
        26: 181,153,143,255
        27: 90,179,223,255
        28: 43,43,41,255
        29: 210,112,92,255
        30: 151,170,109,255
        31: 209,146,116,255
        32: 78,43,5,255
       33: 32,73,43,255
       34: 146,173,145,255
       35: 207,172,116,255
       36: 248,81,11,255
       37: 78,75,43,255
       38: 143,119,110,255
       39: 157,184,214,255
       40: 180,212,209,255
       41: 109,6,0,255
       42: 79,74,9,255
       43: 142,43,9,255
       44: 177,116,106,255
       45: 77,6,0,255
       46: 112,139,111,255
       47: 110,83,73,255
       48: 177,77,45,255
       49: 144,83,71,255
       50: 145,178,178,255
       51: 148,209,179,255
       52: 116,136,74,255
       53: 112,142,143,255
       54: 77,107,77,255
       55: 164,110,144,255
       56: 141,73,14,255
       57: 142,7,0,255
       58: 11,45,91,255
       59: 43,39,9,255
       60: 113,176,145,255
       61: 44,6,0,255
       62: 175,107,49,255
       63: 77,111,114,255
       64: 178,82,72,255
       65: 34,134,167,255
       66: 139,219,251,255
       67: 78,142,111,255
       68: 143,48,37,255
       69: 111,49,37,255
       70: 144,210,214,255
       71: 215,221,239,255
       72: 241,210,152,255
       73: 74,49,40,255
       74: 114,178,182,255
       75: 43,146,211,255
       76: 141,136,50,255
       77: 225,44,6,255
       78: 180,216,242,255
       79: 110,145,180,255
       80: 79,141,145,255
       81: 146,152,174,255
       82: 175,42,9,255
       83: 224,186,191,255
       84: 80,104,42,255
       85: 77,143,184,255
       86: 211,238,153,255
       87: 41,126,100,255
       88: 11,38,10,255
       89: 219,206,133,255
       90: 109,103,16,255
       91: 177,48,39,255
       92: 207,141,82,255
       93: 10,41,41,255
       94: 72,82,109,255
       95: 181,204,119,255
       96: 146,206,148,255
       97: 115,136,50,255
       98: 177,7,0,255
       99: 112,205,184,255
      100: 242,221,239,255
      101: 148,170,84,255
      102: 178,72,13,255
      103: 75,174,186,255
      104: 111,172,116,255
      105: 175,170,84,255
      106: 76,138,81,255
      107: 60,51,70,255
      108: 241,146,132,255
      109: 79,172,145,255
      110: 174,152,172,255
      111: 13,16,22,255
      112: 252,128,26,255
      113: 246,238,143,255
      114: 82,103,15,255
      115: 169,19,116,255
      116: 104,85,103,255
      117: 245,177,137,255
      118: 140,103,16,255
      119: 160,238,218,255
      120: 185,238,167,255
      121: 80,171,114,255
      122: 248,134,78,255
      123: 34,17,23,255
      124: 166,238,186,255
      125: 144,83,106,255
      126: 207,172,83,255
      127: 188,104,20,255
      128: 197,82,103,255
      129: 255,255,255,255
      130: 251,175,74,255
      131: 215,51,97,255
      132: 143,16,20,255
      133: 111,17,19,255
      134: 117,170,83,255
      135: 178,17,21,255
      136: 77,17,19,255
      137: 37,121,64,255
      138: 221,255,204,255
      139: 204,255,187,255
      140: 204,255,204,255
      141: 238,255,221,255
      142: 255,255,238,255
      143: 221,255,187,255
      144: 238,255,204,255
      145: 255,255,221,255
      146: 62,171,90,255
      147: 111,204,136,255
      148: 69,192,236,255
      149: 135,238,255,255
      150: 221,255,221,255
      151: 150,238,151,255
      152: 153,238,255,255
      153: 238,255,238,255
      154: 255,255,204,255
      155: 153,255,255,255
      156: 44,198,174,255
      157: 221,238,187,255
      158: 238,255,255,255
      159: 238,255,187,255
      160: 221,255,238,255
      161: 204,255,221,255
      162: 194,187,136,255
      163: 238,238,238,255
      164: 238,238,204,255
      165: 238,238,187,255
      166: 170,170,119,255
      167: 170,153,97,255
      168: 187,170,119,255
      169: 153,136,85,255
      170: 221,238,170,255
      171: 136,119,61,255
      172: 221,221,221,255
      173: 204,238,170,255
      174: 153,153,102,255
      175: 153,119,64,255
      176: 193,170,136,255
      177: 170,170,170,255
      178: 221,238,204,255
      179: 190,187,189,255
      180: 204,255,170,255
      181: 204,204,198,255
      182: 255,238,238,255
      183: 238,238,221,255
      184: 136,136,68,255
      185: 153,153,85,255
      186: 202,238,187,255
      187: 221,255,255,255
      188: 170,170,102,255
      189: 170,153,119,255
      190: 170,136,102,255
      191: 187,187,153,255
      192: 153,119,85,255
      193: 136,102,68,255
      194: 191,187,118,255
      195: 192,153,124,255
      196: 136,136,85,255
      197: 153,102,60,255
      198: 187,153,99,255
      199: 153,136,102,255
      200: 168,187,119,255
      201: 154,136,67,255
      202: 130,119,85,255
      203: 170,170,136,255
      204: 168,187,136,255
      205: 221,221,192,255
      206: 255,238,221,255
      207: 187,136,95,255
      208: 255,255,0,255
      209: 153,153,126,255
      210: 134,153,85,255
      211: 221,255,170,255
      212: 204,255,238,255
      213: 136,136,102,255
      214: 187,170,102,255
      215: 221,238,221,255
      216: 255,238,204,255
      217: 196,187,170,255
      218: 136,102,89,255
      219: 153,102,89,255
      220: 255,255,186,255
      221: 187,170,153,255
      222: 238,238,170,255
      223: 135,255,255,255
      224: 170,170,153,255
      225: 170,136,123,255
      226: 136,136,131,255
      227: 190,136,126,255
      228: 225,204,196,255
      229: 204,221,193,255
      230: 153,136,125,255
      231: 204,255,255,255
      232: 165,187,153,255
      233: 204,238,204,255
      234: 133,153,102,255
      235: 255,238,184,255
      236: 170,187,170,255
      237: 221,238,238,255
      238: 195,170,170,255
      239: 133,153,126,255
      240: 199,221,221,255
      241: 238,238,255,255
      242: 197,238,221,255
      243: 204,204,222,255
      244: 165,187,187,255
      245: 132,153,67,255
      246: 170,170,189,255
      247: 158,153,67,255
      248: 255,238,255,255
      249: 221,238,255,255
      250: 198,238,238,255
      251: 165,187,101,255
      252: 238,255,169,255
      253: 225,204,222,255
      254: 190,169,188,255
      255: 198,238,255,255
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to put your geotiffs in a directory like this:

```
...\webapps\geoserver\data\data\myGeoTiffs
```

Much more, when creating you store, put this in the **Connection Parameters URL**:

```
file:data/myGeoTiffs
```

---

I've tried also to reproduce your error on my systems but I wasn't able to do it. (In my case everything works well even when I load the tiffs from anywhere outside the `GeoServer` *data directory*).

I think there could be another two possible causes:

1) Something wrong with your data:

Therefore, is it possible for you to upload on `dropbox.com` a zip with your data to be  tested outside your computer? If it loads ok on mine computer then *your ImageMosaic Plugin could be incompatible with your GeoServer version*.

2) If the error appears again, then maybe *the GeoTiffs wasn't properly produced*:

In this case:

a) You could use `gdal_translate`, which could clean up the errors in the GeoTiffs headers.

b) Another approach would be to produce a `vrt` for your tiles. I've upload already such a mosaic **[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/Stackexchange/Mosaic/test.zip)**, for you, to test it.

---

Also, there is possible to see important hints about the error, when you try to create the store, if you check the GeoServer log.

Answer (score 10):

Check the file system permissions for your data directory.

Your servlet container like Tomcat or jetty needs to be able to read AND write files in the directory.

I had the same error using linux bu after correcting the permissions for that specific directory (chown -R tomcat7:tomcat ) everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was spaces in the filename that I had to remove (GeoServer v2.14) and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread, it worked for me https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/geoserver-manager-users/sa1D4kRr62A

In short, the point is if the server hostname does not resolve to an IP address (weird behavior of JAI ImageIO...) the store creation fails.  Ensuring that the hostname resolved corrected the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and in my case changing the permissions(write) on the files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happened because I was using Windows file paths (with backslashes \ instead of /). Changing the url to use normal slash characters solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was Linux systemd restricting the dirs that tomcat is allowed to write to.

In your tomcat.service file, make sure to add the necessary `ReadWritePaths`.  (note: your service file may be named differently. eg geoserver.service)

eg:

```
ReadWritePaths=/opt/geoserver/data/
ReadWritePaths=/path/to/your/images/dir/
```

Also I found that when ImageMosaic plugin creates the dirname.properties file, it set `Heterogeneous` to true and added `MosaicCRS`.  One of these cause problems when I was creating a layer from the data source.  Changing Heterogeneous to false and commenting out MosaicCRS seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite some time since this question was asked but I faced a similar issue today.

In GeoServer Web UI, check the logs under About & Status > **GeoServer Logs**. It's likely that there's an answer there. In my case, the error occured because the directory was not writable. Changing it to `rwxrwxrwx` (0777) fixed the issue.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem twice. And it was two different reasons:

1. HDD was failing and Linux set it as read only.
2. I tried to load files from mounted HDD that had label containing the space char.