# Geoserver 2.5.1 Image Mosaic Plugin

Tags: geoserver

I have geoserver 2.5.1 running on ubuntu 14.04 server. I tried to compose an image mosaic with ImageMosaicPlugin but I always get a message **Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/dalekovod and hints nul**. Images are in the right file format because geoserver recognizes them, and I can load each at one of them separately but I have 120 images.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: do you have write permission to the data directory (or more importantly does the user that is running GeoServer?)

Comment: I have permission to read, write, and execute in geoserver folder. I can load 1 image from that folder,  but Image Mosaic Plugin sends me above mentioned error message.

Comment: This issue needs love and or funding see https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOT-4715?filter=-2

Comment: GEOT-4715 does not have much to do with this issue. It is about error message that does not tell details about what went wrong when something fails when creating the mosaic. Geoserver comes with image mosaic demo and the images are in /data_dir/coverages/mosaic_sample/  Can you make another image mosaic layer by using this directory and files?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two others with the same problem:

- [Could not list layers for this store error when creating new ImageMosaic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171284/could-not-list-layers-for-this-store-error-when-creating-new-imagemosaic)
- [Creating Store in GeoServer using ImageMosaic Plugin gives Error?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87384/creating-store-in-geoserver-using-imagemosaic-plugin-gives-error)

All point to permission problems.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123251)

Comment: Good point! That was literally my first post ever so thank you for helping me