# Can't change store dir or create new raster store on GeoServer 2.16. Failed to create reader from file: data/

Tags: raster, geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff, java

I tryied to change raster source for existing raster store, but face it:

> Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving
>   them: Failed to create reader from
>   file:data/project_data/full_pop_web_2020.tif and hints Hints:
>   REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@246294a2
>   EXECUTOR_SERVICE =
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@70a012d[Running, pool size =
>   0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System
>   defaults: STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FEATURE_FACTORY =
>   org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@403c326e
>   LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl
>   FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING =
>   http GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null
>   COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8

I had found this post: [Creating Store in GeoServer using ImageMosaic Plugin gives Error?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87384/creating-store-in-geoserver-using-imagemosaic-plugin-gives-error)
and I checked / tryed this:

- that owner of dir/file.tif is tomcat
- place a file.tif in /my_workspace/ and /data/data/ - no way
- that file works well in qgis
- that SRID is ok
- space on server is ok

all files version were created by `gdal_translate  2020_web.tif  full_web_2020.tif -co COMPRESS=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES -co "TILED=YES" -scale 0 100 0 100 -a_srs epsg:3857`

**UPD** full log output was added:

```
GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported.  
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported.  
    //.............................................
    ... 159 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported.  
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.imageio.geotiff.GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter.createCoordinateSystem(GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter.java:186)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.getHRInfo(GeoTiffReader.java:331)
    ... 160 more
2020-01-20 17:28:00,813 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:data/data_rasters/full_pop_web_2020.tif
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/data_rasters/full_pop_web_2020.tif and hints Hints:
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@246294a2                                                                                  
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@70a012d[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
System defaults:
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                       
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@403c326e
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                   
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                   
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8
```

so what's the problem?

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: log info was added

Comment: "GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported." - suggests that your SRS is not ok - please add the output from gdalinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with handling EPSG:3857 in GDAL 3.X. You can run transformations with gdal 2.X and geoserver will read this file.

For example, you can use `gdal_translate` from folder "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\gdal2\bin" if you use qgis from OSGeo4W.

Detail information on Geoserver`s JIRA:
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9475

Comment: Thanks ! I tried work with Raster using gdal 2.4.2 and task has been done

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else experiences this issue, and that are not having problems with their data, there is another reason why one might get this error.

For me, who exhibited the same issue, I had a completely different answer - namely if you name your folder for instance, Chlorophyll Mean instead of Chlorophyll_Mean or ChlorophyllMean, this error would appear. I guess the ImageMosaic plugin does not like spaces in the directory names.